# React: unable to check the type of input field

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can I test for the type of the input field in the JSX of my react component?

For example, lets say the following is a part of JSX:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" name="testfield" />
</form>
```

Now I want to write a test case that which should check if the type of the input field is a number or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selectors to find the element in the component, and assert its existence.

```
expect(wrapper.find('input[name="testfield"][type="number"]')).toHaveLength(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have  :

`<form >
     <input type='text' name='name' id='name' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</form>`

You can create a function in the class  like :

`handleChange(event){
   console.log(event.target.type) // Use this to compare the type.
   if ( event.target.type == 'number' ) {// Your case }
}`

You can also use event.target to compare different properties like the name(event.target.name), etc.
In case you have multiple elements inside the `<form>` start by comparing the names of the target so you know what element was changed since we may be using the same handler for each element.

Comment: i want to write a test case in a separate file that checks for the type of the input field in the JSX of react component